# What is the aggregation version of $not?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

```
{ field_name: { $not: { $lt: 100 } } }
```

How do I write the above using MongoDB aggregation language?

I cannot use:

```
{ $gte: ["$field_name", 100] }
```

because `field_name` may be missing. When it is missing, then it should always be true. This is the reason why I use `$not`.

The should be able to use indexes on `field_name`

Comment: Not greater than = Less than or equal to. Negate of `$gt`: `$lte`.

Comment: I edited my question. I cannot use the reverse because the field may be missing. @YongShun

Comment: use or query with exists:false+gte:100 ?

Comment: @cmgchess would that be able to use indexes on `field_name`?

Comment: it should since its a match query? you can do the .explain() to see that

Comment: i meant somethig like https://mongoplayground.net/p/s0wIoeiHKnN

Comment: @cmgchess right, that's what I understood you to mean.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`$not` with `$gt` (not greater than) is equivalent to `$lte` (lesser or equal to).

While you can use the `$ifNull` operator to define the default value if the field is `null` or missing.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
  {
    $match: {
      $expr: {
        $lte: [
          {
            $ifNull: [
              "$field_name",
              0
            ]
          },
          100
        ]
      }
    }
  }
])
```

[Demo @ Mongo Playground](https://mongoplayground.net/p/Ud95RArnaoD)

Comment: Would this be able to use the indexes on `$ifNull`?

Comment: You may check with `.explain()`. But I think cmgchess' comment with the `$or` and `{ $exists: false }` will hit the index.

Answer (score 1):

What is your problem? It should just work:

```
db.collection.insertMany([
   { field_name: 50 },
   { field_name: 150 },
   { other_field: 0 },
   { field_name: null }
])

db.collection.find({ field_name: { $not: { $lt: 100 } } })    
[
  { _id: ObjectId("6459fc29927c6f7dd310d586"), field_name: 150 },
  { _id: ObjectId("6459fc29927c6f7dd310d587"), other_field: 0 },
  { _id: ObjectId("6459fc8e927c6f7dd310d588"), field_name: null }
]


db.collection.aggregate([{ $match: { field_name: { $not: { $lt: 100 } } } }])
[
  { _id: ObjectId("6459fc29927c6f7dd310d586"), field_name: 150 },
  { _id: ObjectId("6459fc29927c6f7dd310d587"), other_field: 0 },
  { _id: ObjectId("6459fc8e927c6f7dd310d588"), field_name: null }
]
```

Index is used in either cases.

[$match documentation](https://www.mongodb.com/docs/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/):

> The `$match` stage has the following prototype form:
>
> `{ $match: { <query> } }`
>
> `$match` takes a document that specifies the query conditions. **The query syntax is identical to the read operation query syntax**